# In Perl, how can I sort hash keys using a custom ordering?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, foreach

I am trying to do work on a hash of files and the work has to be done in a specific order. Most would say the list can be ordered like so:

```
for my $k (sort keys %my_hash)
{
    print "$k=>$my_hash{$k}, ";
}
```

However, I need nonalphabetical order, in fact the keys start with a word then `_` and they go `G` to `digits` to `L` to any of `M,P,R,T or D` (eg. `word_G.txt`,`word_2.txt`,...,`word_P.txt`). Is there any way to sort by custom order?

Comment: just put your sort condition behind the sort keyword:   `while my $k (sort { $a < $b unless $a eq '_' } keys %my_hash)`   etc ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there any way to sort by custom order?

Yes. See [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;

my @order = qw(G 1 2 3 L M P R T D);

my %order_map = map { $order[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#order;

my $pat = join '|', @order;

my @input = qw(word_P.txt word_2.txt word_G.txt);

my @sorted = sort {
    my ($x, $y) = map /^word_($pat)[.]txt\z/, $a, $b;
    $order_map{$x} <=> $order_map{$y}
} @input;

print "@sorted\n";
```

Comment: I see the comparison prototype which I assume is what I want, but the only solution I can see is a bunch of if statements. Is this the only way?

Comment: You haven't really explained you requirements well, so I can't really figure out what would solve the particular problem. To sort in a non-default way, you need to write a comparison function. If you explain that function needs to do, we might be able to help.

Comment: I thought that was as good as I could explain it, so let's put it a different way. Instead of comparing `A,B,C,...,X,Y,Z` I'd like `G,1,2,3,L,M,P,R,T,D`

Comment: On the LHS, you have 26 letters, on the RHS you have 10 characters, so I don't know how those are supposed to map to each other. However, if all you want is to map words that begin with `G` to sort before words that start with `1`, you should be able to adapt the example I posted to suit your needs.

Comment: Your solution works, but has quite a few uninitialized values when I change `@order` of `my @sorted = ...` to `qw(word_P.txt word_2.txt word_G.txt)` is there any way to handle this?

Comment: I thought those were output files.

Comment: they are constructed files that need to be pushed to another location, but your edited answer is very helpful. Thank you so much for the help, I did make one modification. I changed map to `map /^word_($pat)\d?\.txt\z/, $a, $b;`, because some of the files are actually word_P1,word_P2,etc; but that's my fault for not specifying.

Answer (score 4):

```
use 5.014;

sub rank {
    my ($word) = @_;
    $word =~ s{\A \w+ _}{}msx;
    return do {
        given ($word) {
            0 when /\A G/msx;
            1 when /\A [0-9]/msx;
            2 when /\A L/msx;
            3 when /\A [MPRTD]/msx;
            default { 1000 };
        }
    };
}

say for sort { rank($a) <=> rank($b) } qw(word_P.txt word_2.txt word_G.txt);
```

---

Output:

```
word_G.txt
word_2.txt
word_P.txt
```

---

Edit: Before Perl 5.14, use a temporary variable.

```
use 5.010;
⋮
return do {
    my $dummy;
    given ($word) {
        $dummy = 0 when /\A G/msx;
        $dummy = 1 when /\A [0-9]/msx;
        $dummy = 2 when /\A L/msx;
        $dummy = 3 when /\A [MPRTD]/msx;
        default { $dummy = 1000 };
    }
    $dummy;
};
```

Comment: I copy pasted your solution into perl and it's giving me no errors, but order P,2,G which is the supplied order...

Comment: Bumping minimum required version as per http://p3rl.org/perl5140delta#given-return-values

Answer (score 0):

I had a specific use case where I wanted to sort with certain values first, other values last, then everything else alphabetically in the middle.

Here's my solution:

```
my @sorted = sort {
    my @order = qw(Mike Dave - Tom Joe);
    my ($x,$y) = (undef,undef);
    for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#order; $i++) {
        my $token = $order[$i];
        $x = $i if ($token eq $a or (not defined $x and $token eq "-"));
        $y = $i if ($token eq $b or (not defined $y and $token eq "-"));
    }
    $x <=> $y or
    $a cmp $b
} @ARGV;
```

Output:

```
$ perl customsort.pl Tom Z Mike A Joe X Dave G
Mike Dave A G X Z Tom Joe
```